# Loop through files in a folder and countif

Tags: excel, vba, loops, countif

I have this VBA code to count all values that are not zero in all excel files saved in a folder and print out the result in the worbook containing the macro. the problem I am having is that it opens the same file (the first one) over and over instead of moving to the next file.

```
Sub RealCount()

   Dim file As String
   Dim row As Integer
   Dim wb As Workbook

   row = 2    
   file = Dir("\\Daglig rapport\KPI Marknadskommunikation\FEB\*.xl??")
   Do While file <> ""
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\Daglig rapport\KPI Marknadskommunikation\FEB\*.xl??")
      Call ZeroCount
      file = Dir("\\Daglig rapport\KPI Marknadskommunikation\FEB\*.xl??")
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us what you have already tried, where you are stuck etc. this is no code writing service

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  Please post the code you have tried that is not working.

Comment: The 2nd call to dir should only be `Dir()` (no parameters)

Comment: @Shadow: have tried but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some suggestions to get it working:

- Use a `path` variable to keep the folder location and make the code easier to read
- Fix the `Workbooks.Open` so the parameter should be the actual file path (I'm kind of surprised Excel's `Workbook.Open` would actually work with wildcards characters like `*` or `?`)
- Check that `ZeroCount` doesn't call any `Dir` functions. If you do, then Excel may very well reset your ability to call `Dir` to correctly get the next file in your loop. If you find that this is happening and you must absolutely call `Dir` inside of this loop, then you could loop through all the `Dir` values first and store them into an array. Then make another loop that goes through that array which calls `ZeroCount` (or any code that needs to use `Dir` within it)

Here's an example of the first two points taken care of:

```
Sub RealCount()
   Dim path as String
   Dim file As String
   Dim row As Integer
   Dim wb As Workbook

   path = "\\Daglig rapport\KPI Marknadskommunikation\FEB\"
   row = 2    
   file = Dir(path & "*.xl??")
   Do While file <> ""
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & file)
      Call ZeroCount
      row = row + 1     ' I assume you want to increment row each time as well maybe?
      file = Dir()
   Loop
End Sub
```

- For some more examples of using VBA's `Dir` - see here: http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-dir-function/